# UI Not Loading When Using While In Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I am making a program which you can create and load in a flashcard pack using csv files. When a csv file is chosen it opens other UI with the question, answer and image for a flashcard and will keep on looping until all the flashcards in the pack are gone through using a foreach loop.

However the foreach loop would keep on looping without the user pressing the next button. To fix this I did:

```
                while (Continue() == false) { } //this is at the end of the foreach loop

                }
        }

        private bool Continue()
        {
            if (btn_NextFlashcard_WasClicked) return true;
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            Application.DoEvents();
            return false;
        }

        private bool btn_NextFlashcard_WasClicked;

        private void btn_NextFlashcard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_NextFlashcard_WasClicked = true;
        }
```

This fixed the problem of it looping again without the button for the next flashcard being pressed but now it doesn't even open the second UI for me to press the next flashcard button.

**How would I fix this?** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for foreach loop:

```
public void ReadFlashcardPack(string file)
        {
            var records = engine.ReadFile(file);

                foreach (var record in records)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("New foreach loop");

                    lblQuestion.Text = record.question;
                    lblAnswer.Text = record.answer;

                    lblAnswer.Visible = false;
                    btn_NextFlashcard_WasClicked = false;

                    //check if there is an image
                    if (record.image == "FALSE")
                    {
                        Image.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image.Show();
                        Image.Image = Properties.Resources.test_image;
                    }

                    while (Continue() == false) { }

                }
        }
```

The records also come from a class: `[DelimitedRecord(",")]
        public class FlashcardPack
        {
            public string question;
            public string answer;
            public string image;
        }`

And then a new instance of FileHelpers engine is made `private FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack> engine = new FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack>();` to read the csv file and every time the foreach loop loops record.question, record.answer and record.image changes depending on what line the loop is on.

Comment: The `NextFlashcard_Click` tells you when to proceed - you dont need that do nothing loop

Comment: The loop will just go through every flashcard without me pressing the next button.

Comment: And then with the while loop there the second UI doesnt load.

Comment: You should probably restructure this code so there is no need for the loop.  Keep track of the index of the current flashcard and then increment that when the button is pressed and update the U with the information from the next flashcard.  Having a loop on a bool will also eat much CPU which could cause major performance issues which is another reason to restructure the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is to store the list of records outside of the method, keep track of the next record that should be read, and modify the method to just read the next record.

Then, in your click event, you can just call the method again until all records have been read.

```
private string filePath = @"f:\private\temp\temp.csv"; // Use your file path here
private List<FlashcardPack> records;
private int nextRecord;

public void ReadNextRecord()
{
    if (records == null)
    {
        records = engine.ReadFile(filePath).ToList();
        nextRecord = 0;
    }
    else if (nextRecord >= records.Count)
    {
        // Do something when all records have been read
        nextRecord = 0; 
    }

    // Get next record and increment our variable
    var record = records[nextRecord++];

    lblQuestion.Text = record.question;
    lblAnswer.Text = record.answer;

    lblAnswer.Visible = false;
    btn_NextFlashcard_WasClicked = false;

    //check if there is an image
    if (record.image == "FALSE")
    {
        Image.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        Image.Show();
        Image.Image = Properties.Resources.test_image;
    }
}

private void btn_NextFlashcard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadNextRecord();
}
```

---

Here's a working sample that uses the concept above which might help you get your code working, since I can't see your whole project:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<Flashcard> flashcards;
    private int nextRecord;

    // Use a valid path on your system here (the file doesn't need to exist)
    private const string FilePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.csv";

    private void LoadFlashcards()
    {
        flashcards = Engine.ReadFile(FilePath);
        nextRecord = 0;
    }

    public void DisplayNextFlashcard()
    {
        if (flashcards == null)
        {
            LoadFlashcards();
        }
        else if (nextRecord >= flashcards.Count)
        {
            // Do something when all records have been read
            nextRecord = 0;
        }

        var flashcard = flashcards[nextRecord++];

        lblQuestion.Text = flashcard.Question;
        lblAnswer.Visible = false;
        lblAnswer.Text = flashcard.Answer;

        Image.Visible = flashcard.Image;
        Image.Image = Properties.Resources.FlashcardImage;
    }

    private void btn_NextFlashcard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNextFlashcard();
    }
}

class Flashcard
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool Image { get; set; }

    public static Flashcard Parse(string csvLine)
    {
        if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));
        var parts = csvLine.Split(',').Select(item => item.Trim()).ToList();
        if (parts.Count != 3) throw new FormatException(
            "csvLine does not contain 3 comma-separated items.");

        return new Flashcard
        {
            Question = parts[0],
            Answer = parts[1],
            Image = !parts[2].Equals("FALSE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        };
    }
}

class Engine
{
    public static List<Flashcard> ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) CreateFile(filePath);
        return File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(Flashcard.Parse).ToList();
    }

    private static void CreateFile(string filePath)
    {
        File.CreateText(filePath).Close();
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, 
            "What is more useful when it is broken?, An egg, TRUE\n" +
            "What belongs to you but other people use it more?, Your name, FALSE\n" +
            "I have three eyes all in a row. When the red one opens " +
            "no one can go. What am I?, A traffic light, TRUE");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to explain what the record and records variables are

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I thought. Does that invalidate this answer, though? Can you not store `records` as a private field, and then keep track of the next index to read? What type does `engine.ReadFile(file)` return?

Comment: When I run it the `engine.ReadFile(file)` returns `Flashcards.ReadFlashcards+FlashcardPack[]` and the program stops on the line `var record = records[nextRecord++];` with the error ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: That indicates that `records` is `null`. Where do you get the `file` path from? I did not add it to the `Click` event when calling the `ReadRecord` method, but that would produce a different error than what you're seeing. I've updated the sample with code that works on it's own (given that I can't see your project) but you should be able to modify it so it works for your code.

Comment: the file path is from an OpenFileDialog

Comment: It should be fairly trivial to adapt this solution to your existing project.

Comment: I modified the code you provided so I could use it in my project and now it works, thanks for the help :)